# cakephp jquery ui parent page is refreshed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, cakephp, modal-dialog

I am using jquery to show a modal dialog from a view in cakephp to submit a data. problem is, after I submit the data, the original page (before the dialog open) got refreshed. What should I do, so that it's not refreshing the parent page? e.g:

admin_add.ctp (which is a view for article controller)

```
<div>
//...other code
<?php
    echo '<div class="addNewCategory">';
    echo 'add';
    echo '</div>';

?>
//...other code
</div>

<div class="dialog-form" title='Create new Category'>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.dialog-form').dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           title: 'New Category',
           modal: true,
           close: function() {

           }
        });

        $('.addNewCategory').click(function() {
            $('.dialog-form').load('/admin/categories/addmodal').dialog('open');
        });
</script>
```

CategoriesController.ctp

```
public function admin_addmodal() {
    $this->layout=null;

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Category->create();
        if ($this->Category->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The category has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The category could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

and last one is the view for the modal, admin_addmodal.ctp

```
<h2><?php echo __('New Category');?></h2>
<div id="content_wrap">
    <div class="categories form">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Category');?>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
        ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, in general it work. I click the 'add' and it will trigger the modal dialog which is showing admin_addmodal.ctp, and when I fill the data in there and click submit. the data got submitted, and the modal dialog is close. The problem is after that happen, the original page got refreshed (if I redirect it to original page which is admin/article/) or send to '/admin/categories/'.

anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You will have to make an ajax form that you are showing into your model dialog.

Comment: ^ That or open the form using an iframe in the dialog.